# An unwanted default login interface appears

Tags: spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I started a Springboot application looking to create a login/registration Webapp .

I only set up Thymeleaf and Bootstrap for the HTML template , and set up the service, the controller and the repository.
This is the first time this login interface shows and whenever I change the URL it goes back to `localhost:8080/login`

I made sure that the port is set on the current project, and that there is no request set for `/login`

[image]
It looks like there is a backend set up for it and I do not undrestand from where it is ...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is from Springboot security auto configuration , I had to disable it manually adding a configurating class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
     //security.httpBasic().disable(); // Did work only for GET     
     security.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll(); // Works for GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to have security, you can remove Spring Security from your classpath (by removing it from the `pom.xml` if you use Maven). Then you don't need this configuration.